# How to design carousel in material design

Tags: angular, typescript, material-design, carousel, angular6

I am trying to implement carousel in my environment `Angular CLI: 6.0.5` , `Node: 10.1.0`, `OS: win32 x64`, `Angular: 6.0.3` and I am not been able to find the document for designing the carousel in [here](https://material.angular.io/components/categories) as I am new to this design framework. I just want to implement only material design not the bootstrap or any other tool to design carousel. Is there any document for designing carousel or any solution for designing carousel? How can I implement carousel in material design in Angular 6?

Answer (score 0):

Before implementing carousal you first thing that need to be keep in mind is your **outer most div's** width is considered of **100%** and **2nd** div will have the width as **100%*number of carousal containers** and then the each carousal self width which will have actual carousal data will be **100%/number of containers**.

```
Please refer this example : https://codepen.io/nehatawar/pen/xzaVQa
```

You can integrate this type of carousal in any framework.